# Compiling Java Github project fails

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, zanata

I am trying to compile a github project in eclipse: https://github.com/zanata/zanata-platform

After running quickbuild.sh to build a .war file it fails at compiling "zanata-war".

Okapi dependencies:

```
      <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.okapi.filters</groupId>
    <artifactId>okapi-filter-dtd</artifactId>
    <version>${okapi.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>net.sf.okapi.logbind</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.okapi.filters</groupId>
    <artifactId>okapi-filter-html</artifactId>
    <version>${okapi.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>net.sf.okapi.logbind</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.okapi.filters</groupId>
    <artifactId>okapi-filter-idml</artifactId>
    <version>${okapi.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>net.sf.okapi.logbind</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.okapi.filters</groupId>
    <artifactId>okapi-filter-json</artifactId>
    <version>${okapi.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>net.sf.okapi.logbind</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.okapi.filters</groupId>
    <artifactId>okapi-filter-openoffice</artifactId>
    <version>${okapi.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>net.sf.okapi.logbind</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.okapi.filters</groupId>
    <artifactId>okapi-filter-tmx</artifactId>
    <version>${okapi.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>net.sf.okapi.logbind</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.okapi.filters</groupId>
    <artifactId>okapi-filter-plaintext</artifactId>
    <version>${okapi.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>net.sf.okapi.logbind</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.okapi.filters</groupId>
    <artifactId>okapi-filter-regex</artifactId>
    <version>${okapi.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>net.sf.okapi.logbind</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.okapi.filters</groupId>
    <artifactId>okapi-filter-ts</artifactId>
    <version>${okapi.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>net.sf.okapi.logbind</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.okapi.steps</groupId>
    <artifactId>okapi-step-tokenization</artifactId>
    <version>${okapi.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>net.sf.okapi.logbind</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.okapi.steps</groupId>
    <artifactId>okapi-step-wordcount</artifactId>
    <version>${okapi.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>net.sf.okapi.logbind</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.okapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>okapi-core</artifactId>
    <version>${okapi.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>net.sf.okapi.logbind</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
```

Okapi Repository:

```
<repository>
  <id>okapi-cloudbees-release</id>
  <name>okapi-cloudbees-release</name>
  <url>http://repository-okapi.forge.cloudbees.com/release/</url>
  <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </releases>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
</repository>
```

Log:

```css
[INFO] Building Zanata web application 4.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for net.sf.okapi.filters:okapi-filter-dtd:jar:0.29 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for net.sf.okapi.filters:okapi-filter-html:jar:0.29 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for net.sf.okapi.filters:okapi-filter-json:jar:0.29 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for net.sf.okapi.filters:okapi-filter-idml:jar:0.29 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for net.sf.okapi.filters:okapi-filter-openoffice:jar:0.29 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for net.sf.okapi.filters:okapi-filter-plaintext:jar:0.29 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for net.sf.okapi.filters:okapi-filter-regex:jar:0.29 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for net.sf.okapi.filters:okapi-filter-ts:jar:0.29 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-maven) @ zanata-war ---
[INFO] Skipping Rule Enforcement.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:properties (dependency-properties) @ zanata-war ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- gmavenplus-plugin:1.1:addSources (default) @ zanata-war ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- gmavenplus-plugin:1.1:addTestSources (default) @ zanata-war ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- gitdescribe-maven-plugin:2.0:gitdescribe (git-describe) @ zanata-war ---
[INFO] [git, describe]
[INFO] Setting Git Describe: git-unknown
[INFO]
[INFO] --- gmavenplus-plugin:1.1:generateStubs (default) @ zanata-war ---
[INFO] Using Groovy 2.4.7 from project compile classpath to perform generateStubs.
[INFO] No sources specified for stub generation.  Skipping.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- gmavenplus-plugin:1.1:execute (dependency-versions) @ zanata-war ---
[INFO] Using Groovy 2.4.7 from project compile classpath to perform execute.
[INFO] Fetching Groovy script from file:/C:/Users/lob/Downloads/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/server/zanata-war/src/etc/dependencyVersions.groovy.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- l10n-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-2:pseudo (default) @ zanata-war ---
[INFO] Pseudo-localizing messages.properties bundle file.
[INFO] Pseudo-localizing META-INF\apache-deltaspike.properties bundle file.
[INFO] Pseudo-localizing richeditor.properties bundle file.
[INFO] Pseudo-localizing ValidationMessages.properties bundle file.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ zanata-war ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 146 resources
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (print lombok location) @ zanata-war ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [echo] lombok VM arguments for GWT compilation:
     [echo] -javaagent:C:\Users\lob\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.16.6\lombok-1.16.6.jar=ECJ
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ zanata-war ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 687 source files to C:\Users\lob\Downloads\zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0\zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0\server\zanata-war\target\classes
[INFO] /C:/Users/lob/Downloads/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/server/zanata-war/src/main/java/org/zanata/rest/service/LocalesService.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[INFO] /C:/Users/lob/Downloads/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/server/zanata-war/src/main/java/org/zanata/rest/service/LocalesService.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO] /C:/Users/lob/Downloads/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/server/zanata-war/src/main/java/org/zanata/dao/ProjectDAO.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /C:/Users/lob/Downloads/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/server/zanata-war/src/main/java/org/zanata/dao/ProjectDAO.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] COMPILATION WARNING :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] /C:/Users/lob/Downloads/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/server/zanata-war/src/main/java/org/zanata/webhook/events/DocumentMilestoneEvent.java:[45,1] Generating equals/hashCode implementation but without a call to superclass, even though this class does not extend java.lang.Object. If this is intentional, add '@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)' to your type.
[WARNING] /C:/Users/lob/Downloads/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/server/zanata-war/src/main/java/org/zanata/webhook/events/TestEvent.java:[20,1] Generating equals/hashCode implementation but without a call to superclass, even though this class does not extend java.lang.Object. If this is intentional, add '@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)' to your type.
[WARNING] /C:/Users/lob/Downloads/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/server/zanata-war/src/main/java/org/zanata/webhook/events/DocumentStatsEvent.java:[45,1] Generating equals/hashCode implementation but without a call to superclass, even though this class does not extend java.lang.Object. If this is intentional, add '@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)' to your type.
[WARNING] /C:/Users/lob/Downloads/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/server/zanata-war/src/main/java/org/zanata/action/ProjectHome.java:[208,5] Not generating getSelectedEnabledLocales(): A method with that name already exists
[WARNING] /C:/Users/lob/Downloads/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/server/zanata-war/src/main/java/org/zanata/action/ProjectHome.java:[277,20] Not generating setSelectedProjectType(): A method with that name already exists
[WARNING] /C:/Users/lob/Downloads/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/server/zanata-war/src/main/java/org/zanata/action/VersionHome.java:[902,5] Not generating getSelectedEnabledLocales(): A method with that name already exists
[WARNING] /C:/Users/lob/Downloads/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/server/zanata-war/src/main/java/org/zanata/webhook/events/ProjectMaintainerChangedEvent.java:[23,1] Generating equals/hashCode implementation but without a call to superclass, even though this class does not extend java.lang.Object. If this is intentional, add '@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)' to your type.
[WARNING] /C:/Users/lob/Downloads/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/server/zanata-war/src/main/java/org/zanata/webhook/events/VersionChangedEvent.java:[47,1] Generating equals/hashCode implementation but without a call to superclass, even though this class does not extend java.lang.Object. If this is intentional, add '@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)' to your type.
[WARNING] /C:/Users/lob/Downloads/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/server/zanata-war/src/main/java/org/zanata/webhook/events/SourceDocumentChangedEvent.java:[23,1] Generating equals/hashCode implementation but without a call to superclass, even though this class does not extend java.lang.Object. If this is intentional, add '@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)' to your type.
[INFO] 9 warnings
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/lob/Downloads/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/server/zanata-war/src/main/java/org/zanata/adapter/HTMLAdapter.java:[64,14] cannot access net.sf.okapi.filters.abstractmarkup.AbstractMarkupFilter
  class file for net.sf.okapi.filters.abstractmarkup.AbstractMarkupFilter not found
[ERROR] /C:/Users/lob/Downloads/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/server/zanata-war/src/main/java/org/zanata/adapter/PlainTextAdapter.java:[33,14] cannot access net.sf.okapi.lib.extra.filters.CompoundFilter
  class file for net.sf.okapi.lib.extra.filters.CompoundFilter not found
[INFO] 2 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] FAILURE build of project org.zanata:zanata-war
[INFO] Builder state: blocked=0 finished=7 ready-or-running=0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Zanata server modules .............................. SUCCESS [  1.129 s]
[INFO] zanata-liquibase ................................... SUCCESS [  2.875 s]
[INFO] security-common .................................... SUCCESS [  2.875 s]
[INFO] Zanata model ....................................... SUCCESS [  1.391 s]
[INFO] Zanata frontend .................................... SUCCESS [01:19 min]
[INFO] gwt-editor ......................................... SUCCESS [  7.344 s]
[INFO] Zanata web application ............................. FAILURE [ 15.626 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:36 min (Wall Clock)
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-28T13:42:41+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 81M/438M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project zanata-war: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/lob/Downloads/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/server/zanata-war/src/main/java/org/zanata/adapter/HTMLAdapter.java:[64,14] cannot access net.sf.okapi.filters.abstractmarkup.AbstractMarkupFilter
[ERROR] class file for net.sf.okapi.filters.abstractmarkup.AbstractMarkupFilter not found
[ERROR] /C:/Users/lob/Downloads/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/zanata-platform-platform-4.0.0/server/zanata-war/src/main/java/org/zanata/adapter/PlainTextAdapter.java:[33,14] cannot access net.sf.okapi.lib.extra.filters.CompoundFilter
[ERROR] class file for net.sf.okapi.lib.extra.filters.CompoundFilter not found
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :zanata-war
```

Comment: If you have followed any instructions exactly and those don't work, I'd file an issue. https://zanata.atlassian.net/projects/ZNTA/issues/ZNTA-1415?filter=allopenissues

Comment: `class file for net.sf.okapi.filters.abstractmarkup.AbstractMarkupFilter not found`

Comment: `quickbuild.sh` isn't in the instructions, by the way.

Comment: @cricket_007 it is in the version before: https://github.com/zanata/zanata-server#quickly-build-a-war-file. In the new version I don't have a clue what build.sh is meant: https://github.com/zanata/zanata-platform#quickly-build-a-war-file-for-later-tests-or-docker-deployment

Comment: It isn't `build.sh`, it is only `./build`. You can see the script here. https://github.com/zanata/zanata-platform/blob/master/build

Comment: @cricket_007 can you tell me how to run that script?

Comment: You need a Linux computer...

Comment: I have a mac. Using $build --all returns: 
"--all: command not found"

Comment: And what would be the command for Windows? :)